# What should I do next when I got the return data of Alamofire?

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I use Alamofire to request the data from a website and then I print out the result in this way:

```
if let resultData = response.result.value {
    print(resultJson)
}
```

It appears in the console like this:

```
(
        {
        name = "Liu Bei";
        strength = 4;
        wisdom = 5;
    },
        {
        name = "Guan Yu";
        strength = 7;
        wisdom = 5;
    },
        {
        name = "Zhang Fei";
        strength = 7;
        wisdom = 3;
    }
)
```

Its type seems to be AnyObject, however what type can I parse it so that I can get the data such as name and strength of each character?

Comment: the closest type is `[[String:AnyObject]]` which is an array of dictionaries with `String` keys and `AnyObject` values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As vadian already stated in the comments.

The JSON type is `[[String:AnyObject]]`

```
if let resultArray = jsonResult as? [[String:AnyObject]]{
    for dictionary in resultArray{
        print(dictionary['name'])
        if let strength = dictionary['strength'] as? Int{
            print(strength)
        }
    }
}
```

This code will first check to see if the JSON is indeed of type `[[String:AnyObject]]`. It will than iterate over the array and print every name and strength in the array.

Comment: Thank you very much. Solved!